# jQuery TouchSwipe plugin doesn't work on links?

Tags: jquery, touchswipe

Im using the jQuery TouchSwipe plugin. Its working great on divs but its not working at all on links.

I want it so if you tap or click a link you get the default link behaviour. But if you swipe I want the javascript swipe to fire as if the element was a div.

https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin

Comment: Perhaps this will be more suitable > https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Touch-Events Written by yours truly :)

Comment: @BenM - thanks for this.  Yours is the best and probably only maintained jquery plugin out there!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What a wonderful question. To solve this for you, I went into the source code. You should know that anchor swiping is **disabled** by default.

> version: 1.5.0    - Added excludedElements, a jquery selector that specifies child elements that do NOT trigger swipes. By default, this is one select that removes all form, input select, button and **anchor elements** ([source](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin/blob/master/jquery.touchSwipe.js)).

**Defaults:**

```
excludedElements:"label, button, input, select, textarea, a, .noSwipe"
```

Simply pass in the `excludedElements` option sans the anchor tag to make swiping work on links:

```
$("a").swipe({
  // Generic swipe handler for all directions
  swipe: function(event, direction) {
    $(this).text("You swiped " + direction);
  },
  excludedElements: "label, button, input, select, textarea, .noSwipe"
});
```

---

There is one more key to this puzzle. You must not set `threshold: 0` as internally that will disable all tap/click events. Set `threshold` to anything higher than 0, or omit it completely. If you make it `threshold: 1`, it will  permit only very still mouse clicks, else swipes will be interpreted.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

---

### Demo 1 - Swipe detected after finger/mouse up

```js
$(function() {
  // Enable swiping...
  $(".test").swipe({
    // Generic swipe handler for all directions
    swipe: function(event, direction) {
      $(this).text("You swiped " + direction);
    },
    excludedElements: "label, button, input, select, textarea, .noSwipe",
    threshold:1
  });

  // Stackoverflow disables snippets opening links, so this captures clicks for a demo
  $(".test").on("click", function(e){
    alert($(this)[0].nodeName + " was clicked");
  });
});
```

```css
.test {font-size: 48px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script><script src="http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" class="test">Please swipe me</a><br><br><div class="test">Please swipe me</div>
```

---

### Demo 2 - Swipe detected after a threshold

This version will detect a swipe after the finger/mouse has swept over `threshold` pixels *before* releasing the finger/mouse. This method works by detecting a swipe and setting some `data` in the link which is read by the first click handler which then blocks *one* click event propagation.

The `.on("click", function(event) {` handler must be the first handler in the jQuery event chain, so place all this code near the top of your page, ideally just below where jQuery is loaded.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".test").swipe({
    swipe: function(event, direction) {
      $(this).text("You swiped " + direction);
    },
    swipeStatus: function(event, phase) {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.data("stopclick", true); // Signal a temporarily click block
      if(phase === $.fn.swipe.phases.PHASE_CANCEL) {
        // Swipe was canceled, so unblock click handers
        $this.data("stopclick", false);
      }
    },
    excludedElements: "label, button, input, select, textarea, .noSwipe",
    threshold:10,
    triggerOnTouchEnd: false
  })
  .on("click", function(event) {
    // Prevent click event propogation for one click 
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.data("stopclick") === true) {
       event.stopImmediatePropagation();
       event.preventDefault();
       $this.data("stopclick", false); // Restore click propogation
    }
  });
  
  // Stackoverflow disables snippets opening links, so this captures clicks for a demo
  $(".test").on("click", function(e){
    alert($(this)[0].nodeName + " was clicked");
  });
});
```

```css
.test {font-size: 48px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script><script src="http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" class="test">Please swipe me</a><br><br><div class="test">Please swipe me</div>
```

Comment: This is working except the link if triggered when I drag on it. I need the link to be triggered if I tap or click on it, but not if I drag. Would you mind extending your answer? Thanks

Comment: That happens on "confusing" swipes (or drags). The easiest solution is set `threshold:1` so only on still clicks will a click occur. I've updated my snippet above. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: $(".main-menu a").swipe({
        swipeRight: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
          $('body').removeClass('oc-menu-open');
          // event.preventDefault();
        },
        excludedElements: ".noSwipe",
        threshold: 100
      });

Comment: It still isnt working for me. Ive tried adding an event prevent default (see my code above).

Comment: Yes it does, but could that not be the e.preventDefault(); that you've used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79951/discussion-between-jdln-and-drakes).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't optimal, but you can use any element with styling similar to that of a link, and handle the direction parameter like so.

```
$("#swipable").swipe( {
    swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
        if (direction == null) {
            location.href = 'somewhere.html'
        } else {
            // Do something else...
        }
    },
     threshold:0
  });
```

Here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/q3gnt8s5/8/

PS. Just noticed how old this post is, hope it 'll be of some use either way, haha

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me. I already have HTML links on the page. When you click the link I want it to be followed as is the default behavior. However when you swipe the link I need to execute some JavaScript.

Comment: So if you click the link, it should work as it is. But if you swipe it, do some other action? Isn't that what you mean? Because that's what I do in the example. I just don't exactly use a link... Just to clarify, you have to add the location.href = 'desired.html' in order to make it work as a link.

Comment: Yes that's what Im trying to do. However I already have links in the HTML and for a number of best practice reasons I dont want to make these javascript reliant as is the case in your solution.

Comment: Yeah, thought as much. Will look into it a little further just in case, good luck either way.