# Href Links In A List Not Clickable On Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I have href links in a  list not being clickable on mobile but they are working just fine on desktop. The links are however working when I long press, so I do not think there is any element accidentally covering them.

Please note that the last two links are toggled to reveal child links using JQuery. Here is the list html;

```html
<div class="sk-navigation">
  <ul class="sk-left-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="shops.html"><i class="fa fa-cubes fa-nav-shops"></i>Shops</a></li>
    <li class="cart-left"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket fa-nav-cart"></i>Shopping Cart</a><span><div class="cart-bubble-left">12</div></span></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-address-book"></i>Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>Admin</a></li>
    <li class="sk-left-parent"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i>Help<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Buyers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Suppliers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dispute</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Report Abuse</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sk-left-parent"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>Info<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tips</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quotes</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can someone please help. The page can be found at http://synergykinetics.com/sales-press-prototype

Comment: The full content of your question must be in your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to create one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: @Rory McCrossan. I  have added a code snippet

Comment: i had the same isuue , i think i solved it by removing a bootstrap class the class name was like  rollback or fallback..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit was a JQuery script I am using called TouchSwipe which was interfering with the clicks. I commented out the threshold option which was set to 0.

I found the solution from as answer in this question: [Tap events not triggering for TouchSwipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273929/tap-events-not-triggering-for-touchswipe)